# Netty 5 after bind issue

Tags: java, networking, netty, bind

Okay so here's my problem:

I'm building a netty 5 server in purpose of learning, but i came across this problem, Which is after binding problem:

So when i bind an port in [netty 5](http://netty.io) i do as this code:

`bind(port).channel().closeFuture().sync();`

Now the code that come after that line won't execute, code such as:
`System.out.println("Server bound!");`

How do i make it execute that code after binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sync()` call to the future object is a blocking call meaning it will wait for the socket to terminate. If you want some code to run after the bind then you will need to do something like:

```
ChannelFuture future = bind(port).channel().closeFuture();

System.out.println("Bound to port!");

future.sync(); // this will block until the port is shut down
```

Comment: He also has the option of not syncing (thus not blocking) the thread so long as another non-daemon thread is doing work. (For example, a task processing engine in this case of RSPS.)